# mongo-db Aggregation query working on mongo shell but not in java program

Tags: java, mongodb

I am working on a project in which i have a huge collection in inside my mongo db. Now I have to get some details from the mongo db which are pretty much smiliar like SQL group by clause. I  successfully executed the query on mongo shell :

```
    > db.votes.aggregate(
    ... { $group : {
    ... _id : "vote_post_id",
    ... votesPerId : { $sum : 1 }
    ... }}
    ... );
    {
"result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "vote_post_id",
                    "votesPerId" : 27371750
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1

    }
    >
```

Now while executing the query from a java proggram I am facing follwing error :

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.CommandResult$CommandFailure: command 
    failed [aggregate]: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , 
    "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)"
     , "code" : 16389 , "ok" : 0.0}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.aggregate(DBCollection.java:1311)
    at main.Connetion.CheckConnection.GetNoOfVotesForAType(CheckConnection.java:210)
    at main.DAO.Votes.VoteDAO.findKeyWord(VoteDAO.java:109)
    at main.DAO.Votes.VoteDAO.main(VoteDAO.java:139)
```

I have debugged my java program and it is producing the exact query what I wrote on mongo shell :

```
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$vote_post_id" , "count" : { "$sum" : 1}}}
```

I have been through a lot of answers for this problem and none seems to solve the issue.

My java code for creating the aggregation function :

// create our pipeline operations, first with the $match
        DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("vote_type_id", "1") );

```
    // build the $projection operation
    DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("vote_post_id", 1);
    fields.put("_id", 0);
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );

    // Now the $group operation
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$vote_post_id");
    groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

    // run aggregation
    AggregationOutput output = votesCollection.aggregate( match, project, group );

    System.out.println(output.getCommandResult());
```

Comment: Please check your values, because for the first time there is one aggregation query, in Java code you are using other aggregation query, and the "debug query" is also different.

Answer (score 1):

To make your query the same as in shell it would be:

```
// $group operation
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "vote_post_id");
groupFields.put("votesPerId", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", 1));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

// run aggregation
AggregationOutput output = votesCollection.aggregate( group );

System.out.println(output.getCommandResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your shell query you're doing

```
_id : "vote_post_id",
```

but in your Java query you're doing

```
"_id", "$vote_post_id"
```

The difference is the dollar sign.  `$vote_post_id` substitutes the value of that field to use as the bucket keys, whereas `vote_post_id` just uses that literal value (so there's just one bucket).